# trouble inserting data in SQLITE3 col on osX

Tags: iphone, sqlite, png, terminal

How can you insert a file data(png) to col in SQLITE3 on osx (command line) and what is the better type to use as a container? blob or binary?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a way from the SQLite monitor to load binary data into a column.  Your best bet is to write a small program to do what you need -- shouldn't be more than a few lines of Perl, Ruby, or Python.